# PHP pop up box with if statement

Tags: php

I have validate my form. I want to pop up a validation message which is "Information has some error,please insert the proper information." but it came out 2 pop up box which is "Information has some error,please insert the proper information." and "Thank You! your order has been placed!". May i know what is the problem?

```
    $fnameErr=$lnameErr=$add1Err=$add2Err=$postErr=$mobileErr=$creditErr=$pinErr ="";
    $credit=$pin="";

    if($_REQUEST['command']=='update')
    {
    $date     = date('Y-m-d');
    $time     = date("H:i:s");
    $charge   = $_REQUEST['ocharge'];
    $fname    = $_REQUEST['ofname'];
    $lname    = $_REQUEST['olname'];
    $mobile   = $_REQUEST['omobile'];
    $add1     = $_REQUEST['oadd1'];
    $add2     = $_REQUEST['oadd2'];
    $postcode = $_REQUEST['opostcode'];
    $state    = $_REQUEST['ostate'];
    $country  = $_REQUEST['ocountry'];
    $credit   = $_REQUEST['ocredit'];
    $pin      = $_REQUEST['opin'];
    $city     = $_REQUEST['ocity'];

if($fname==""||$lname==""||$mobile==""||$add1 ==""||$add2 ==""||$postcode==""||$state ==""||$country==""||$credit==""||$pin==""||$city=="")
{
?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            alert("Please fill in all the required informations.");
        </script>
<?php
        }

        else
        {

        $sql=" INSERT INTO `order` (Order_Date,Order_Time,Delivery_Charge,
                            Delivery_Fname,Delivery_Lname,Delivery_HP,Delivery_Street1,
                            Delivery_Street2,Delivery_Postcode,Delivery_State,
                            Delivery_Country,Credit_No,Pin_No,Delivery_City,Order_Status) 

                            VALUES 

                            ('$date','$time','$charge','$fname','$lname','$mobile',
                            '$add1','$add2','$postcode','$state','$country',
                            '$credit','$pin','$city','Pending')";

        $result=mysql_query($sql);

        if($result === FALSE)
        {
                die("Query Failed!".mysql_error().$result);
        }

        $orderid=mysql_insert_id();   

        if (empty($errors) === true)
        {
        //fname xx
            if (!preg_match("/^[A-Z][a-zA-Z -]+$/i", $_REQUEST['ofname'])) 
            {
                $fnameErr= 'Your first name cannot contain with any symbol and number';
            }
        //lname xx
            if (!preg_match("/^[A-Z][a-zA-Z -]+$/i",$_REQUEST['olname']) )
            {
                $lnameErr= 'Your last name cannot contain with any symbol and number';
            }
        //add1 xx
            if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9 _.,:\"\']+$/i",$_REQUEST['oadd1'])) 
            {
                $add1Err = 'Address 1 must be only letters, numbers or one of the following';   
            }

        //add2 xx
            if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9 _.,:\"\']+$/i",$_REQUEST['oadd2'])) 
            {
                $add2Err= 'Address 2 must be only letters, numbers or one of the following';    
            }
        //postcode xx
            if (!preg_match("/^\d{5}$/i", $_REQUEST['opostcode'])) 
            {
                $postErr = 'Postcode must be 5 digits';

            }   
        //mobile xx
            if (!preg_match("/^\d{3}-\d{7}$/i", $_REQUEST['omobile'])) 
            {
                $mobileErr= 'Phone must comply with this mask: 010-1111111 or 0111-1111111';    
            }
        //credit card xx
            if (!preg_match("/^\d{4}-\d{4}-\d{4}-\d{4}$/i", $_REQUEST['ocredit'])) 
            {
                $creditErr= 'Credit Card must comply with this mask: 0000-1111-2222-3333';

            }
        //pin xx
            if (!preg_match("/^\d{6}$/i", $_REQUEST['opin'])) 
            {
                $pinErr = 'Pin must be 6 digits';   
            }
            ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        alert("Information has some error,please insert the proper information.");
        </script>
    <?php
    }
        $max=count($_SESSION['cart']);
        for($i=0;$i<$max;$i++)
        {
            $pid=$_SESSION['cart'][$i]['productid'];
            $q=$_SESSION['cart'][$i]['qty'];
            $price=get_price($pid);

            $insert_query="INSERT INTO order_detail (Order_ID,Product_ID,Order_Quantity,Sub_Total) VALUES ('$orderid','$pid','$q','$price')";   

            if(mysql_query($insert_query))
            {
                echo"<script>alert('Thank You! your order has been placed!')</script>";
            }
        }

        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: This is really where Javascript comes in. Can this not be done via pure Javascript, or if the validation needs some PHP functionality, use AJAX to test? And while im here, `mysql_query` is **deprecated**. Have a look at PDO or `mysqli_*`.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that saving credit card numbers and PIN numbers in your DB is not PCI compliant ( http://www.pcicomplianceguide.org/pcifaqs.php ).

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't seem to be structure correctly.  You are checking individual fields for errors, then displaying an error message regardless of whether any errors are present.  After that you are continuing on to save the information and display the other alert regardless of what happened with error checking.

Without going too much into the specifics of your code, one way of structuring it would be:

```
$errors = array();
//fname xx
if (!preg_match("/^[A-Z][a-zA-Z -]+$/i", $_REQUEST['ofname'])) 
{
    $fnameErr= 'Your first name cannot contain with any symbol and number';
    array_push($errors, $fnameErr);
}
//lname xx
if (!preg_match("/^[A-Z][a-zA-Z -]+$/i",$_REQUEST['olname']) )
{
    $lnameErr= 'Your last name cannot contain with any symbol and number';
    array_push($errors, $lnameErr);
}
//add1 xx
if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9 _.,:\"\']+$/i",$_REQUEST['oadd1'])) 
{
    $add1Err = 'Address 1 must be only letters, numbers or one of the following';   
    array_push($errors, $add1Err);
}

//add2 xx
if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9 _.,:\"\']+$/i",$_REQUEST['oadd2'])) 
{
    $add2Err= 'Address 2 must be only letters, numbers or one of the following';    
    array_push($errors, $add2Err);
}
//postcode xx
if (!preg_match("/^\d{5}$/i", $_REQUEST['opostcode'])) 
{
    $postErr = 'Postcode must be 5 digits';
    array_push($errors, $postErr);
}   
//mobile xx
if (!preg_match("/^\d{3}-\d{7}$/i", $_REQUEST['omobile'])) 
{
    $mobileErr= 'Phone must comply with this mask: 010-1111111 or 0111-1111111';    
    array_push($errors, $mobileErr);
}
//credit card xx
if (!preg_match("/^\d{4}-\d{4}-\d{4}-\d{4}$/i", $_REQUEST['ocredit'])) 
{
    $creditErr= 'Credit Card must comply with this mask: 0000-1111-2222-3333';
    array_push($errors, $creditErr);
}
//pin xx
if (!preg_match("/^\d{6}$/i", $_REQUEST['opin'])) 
{
    $pinErr = 'Pin must be 6 digits';   
    array_push($errors, $pinErr);
}

if(count($errors) > 0) {
?>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    alert("Information has some error,please insert the proper information.");
    </script>

<?php
}
else {
    $max=count($_SESSION['cart']);
    for($i=0;$i<$max;$i++)
    {
        $pid=$_SESSION['cart'][$i]['productid'];
        $q=$_SESSION['cart'][$i]['qty'];
        $price=get_price($pid);

        $insert_query="INSERT INTO order_detail (Order_ID,Product_ID,Order_Quantity,Sub_Total) VALUES ('$orderid','$pid','$q','$price')";   

        if(mysql_query($insert_query))
        {
            echo"<script>alert('Thank You! your order has been placed!')</script>";
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Finally, note that `mysql_` family of functions is deprecated and you should stop using them as soon as possible.  Use PDO instead of, at least, `mysqli_` functions.